# Can I cap the amount of items I add to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, input

I have my app that is using a text input to add items to an array. I would like to be able to say, once this array has = to 50 items, then disable the search input. I use a "clear completed" button to clear tasks(items) that are checked off. So the only way to re-enable the input would be to clear some items.

I am using Angular.JS, I'm assuming I would need a for loop that says something along the lines, if items = 50, then disable text-input, else enable input.

I just don't know how to go about writing it...

**Angular Array**

```
 $scope.todos = [
    {text:'Build this ToDo List', done:true},         
    {text: 'Test this ToDo list', done:false}
    //tasks added through text input...
  ];
```

**HTML of the app:**

```
<div class="todo-wrapper" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <form>
        <input class="add-input" placeholder="Add a new task..." type="text" ng-model="formTodoText" ng-model-instant/>
        <button class="add-btn" ng-click="addTodo()"><h2>+</h2></button>
      </form>
      <div class="max-window">
        <ul>
          <li class="tasks" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            <label class="label--checkbox">
              <input class="checks" type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" checked/>
              <span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button class="clear-btn" ng-click="clearCompleted()">Clear completed</button>
    </div>
```

**Angular Functions**

*Add item to array*

```
$scope.addTodo = function () {
    $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.formTodoText, done:false});
    $scope.formTodoText = '';
  };
```

*Clear completed tasks(items) from array*

```
$scope.clearCompleted = function () {
        $scope.todos = _.filter($scope.todos, function(todo){
            return !todo.done;
        });
```

*If/Else Statement ?*

```
if ($scope.todos = 50) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('add-input').disabled = true;
    document.getElementsByClassName('add-btn').disabled = true;
} else {
    document.getElementsByClassName('add-input').disabled = false;
    document.getElementsByClassName('add-btn').disabled = false;
}
```

Alternatively, if I could just disable the `add-btn` and `enter to submit` this could solve my problem as well.  Is this possible?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

Problem was solved by using `ng-disabled`

**input**

```
<input class="add-input" placeholder="Add a new task..." type="text" ng-model="formTodoText" ng-model-instant ng-disabled="todos.length >= 4"/>
```

**button**

```
<button class="add-btn" ng-click="addTodo()"ng-disabled="todos.length >= 4"><h2>+</h2></button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the ng-disabled directive on your input :

```
<input class="add-input" placeholder="Add a new task..." type="text" ng-model="formTodoText" ng-model-instant ng-disabled="todos.length >= 50"/>
```

The expression in ng-disabled is a boolean and will disable the input when true, enable it when false.

Comment: I want to disable it, ONLY after a certain number of entries, it seems like you're telling me to just make it disabled from start?

Comment: No, when the todos.length property is modified in your controller's scope, its value will be reflected on the DOM.

Comment: my apologies, I didn't realize the code boxes were able to scroll left. This is what I got working for me: **Input** `<input class="add-input" placeholder="Add a new task..." type="text" ng-model="formTodoText" ng-model-instant ng-disabled="todos.length >= 4"/>` and  **Button** `<button class="add-btn" ng-click="addTodo()"ng-disabled="todos.length >= 4"><h2>+</h2></button>`   Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property of array.

> The length property represents an unsigned, 32-bit integer that specifies the number of elements in an array

*Code*

```
if($scope.todos.length == 50)
```

---

You can also use [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive

> This directive sets the disabled attribute on the element if the `expression` inside `ngDisabled` evaluates to `truthy`.

```
<button ng-disabled="todos.length == 50" ng-click="addTodo()"><h2>+</h2></button>
```